# How get Telegram.Bot.Types.Update through webhook?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

Is any way here to make accept Telegram.Bot.Types.Update update?

Currently, I have this code, but I would like to use Telegram objects

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<OkResult> Post([FromBody]TelegramUpdate update) //my model
    {
        //code
    }
```

When I passing that I getting 400 Bad Request

Through Postman is 415 Unsupported Media Type and Bad request

If I hits controller by InlineKeyboard breakpoint works but with object with null values. 
In console (ngrok) shown 200 ok and then 400 Bad Request

Comment: does this help: https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/#the-new-way-in-asp-net-core

Answer (score 2):

Install Nuget package "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson"

And use it on your Startup.cs file:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Robson Previato,

Install Nuget package "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson"

and using it in Controllers help me

> services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).